# Is there an upper bound of CDF of Normal random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, gaussian

Suppose $W\sim N(0,1)$.

Is there an upper bound of the probability $P(W\le t)$?

Answer (score 2):

There are a great many such upper bounds or, equivalently, lower bounds on the Mills ratio $P(W>t)/f(t)$, where $f$ is the standard normal pdf. See e.g. 
[this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwiBxtH6-eLlAhWsmOAKHXMLD5oQFjABegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Froma.stat.wisc.edu%2Fcourses%2Fst771-newton%2Fpapers%2FBiometrika-1954-SHENTON-177-89.pdf&usg=AOvVaw13aWuR-eMEUJHep9bmmRnm) and [this](https://eudml.org/doc/122588) and references therein.